# jQuery/JS random image positioning using Math.random() and .css?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to programming. Right now I'm using jQuery + jqueryrotate to rotate my images randomly so it looks like they are scattered. I managed to make them rotate randomly, but I am a little stuck on how to make the position random. I made all the images `position: absolute` in a `position: relative` div with class `.holder`. I know usually the css property using jquery should normally be `({"top": "4px"})` but I want it doesn't work when I wrap it around a toString function.

```
$.each($('.holder img'), function (i, element) {
    $(element).rotate(Math.random() * -90 + Math.random() * 90);
    $(element).css({
        "top": Math.random() * 300;
    })
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a unit top doesn't know what you mean, try this:

```
$.each($('.holder img'), function(i, element){
    $(element).rotate(Math.random() * -90 + Math.random() * 90);
    $(element).css({
        "top": (Math.random() * 300) + "px"
    })
});
```

Comment: thanks Mythril. worked well. But can you explain why you don't have to convert (Math.random() * 300) to a string? I thought in JS "+" operators would just concatenate the two since one of them ("px" in this case) was a string

Answer (score 2):

```
$(element).css({
    "top": Math.random() * 300;
});
```

should be

```
$(element).css({
    "top": Math.random() * 300
});
```

remove `;` or it'll trigger a sintax error.

Answer (score 0):

You just add `+ "px"` at the end of the CSS value of the `top` attribute

```
$(element).css({
    "top": (Math.random () * 300) + "px"
});
```